# Is there an URL to open the Gmail compose window with a specific message ID in full-screen (pop-out)

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, google-api-client, gmail-api

I use the new [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) to create a draft for my user. The API response provides the newly created message ID.

I can then open the compose window with the URL`https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=[message-id]`. However I would like to open a full-screen (popped-out) compose window. Is there an URL for that ? This URL must of course be parameterised with the message id.

To be more precise, [this is what I get](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/notwhatiwant.php), and [this is what I want](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/whatiwant.php).

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I use C#, but my problem does not seem to be language related.

Comment: @DaniSpringer No, I known how to open a compose window for a new message, what I need is to open a compose window for an existing message.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail?authuser=me@gmail.com#all/{message_id}
```

Just replace {message_id} with the actual ID string.

Comment: Your URL is similar to the one I provided, the difference being that the mail list is "All Mail" instead of "Drafts". I do not want to open a mail list, I want to open a full screen compose window like [this one](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/whatiwant.php).

Comment: @cao It's similar but different, notice the `authuser`

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why this answer got upvoted? I don't see that it answers the question any better than the original question's URL format; I don't see how including `authuser` moves us closer to a full-screen pop-out. (I'm not trying to be negative, I'm just confused that others are finding this helpful; am I missing something?)