# How to open gmail compose mail box in popup when click on any email id as the logged in user?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a list of my users in one of my website. The list contains various email ids. I want to open gmail compose mail box in popup when click on any email id. If i am logged in with someone@example.com then mail should be send from someone@example.com to clicked email id. I am using method explained in this url
[gmail compose mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548210/is-there-an-url-to-open-the-gmail-compose-window-with-a-specific-message-id-in-f)

But when i click on the solution url in given example it ask for gmail login everytime. But i want to send email using the email id i am login with. That email id is made with my domain like email@domain.com. So what should i do to integrate this thing into my website.

Comment: Is the user logged in to your website, or his Gmail account? Because the user will be asked to login if he/she is not already logged in to their Gmail account.

Comment: no user is logged in to my website.

Comment: Unless the user is already logged in to their Gmail account, they will be asked to login in order to compose and send an email. If you want this to be automatic, as far as I know, you have the option of integrating Google Sign in in your website, so that people sign in to your website using their Google accounts instead of your own website's accounts.

Comment: How to open this compose mail box in popup ?

Comment: So you're okay with the user auth screen everytime? And now you just want it to open up in a pop-up window?

Comment: yes, i want to open this in popup window.